# python-numpy no installation candidate

Tags: software-installation, packages

i want to install the command
sudo apt-get install python-dev-is-python2 python-numpy libtbb2 libtbb-dev libjpeg-dev libpng-dev libtiff-dev libjasper-dev libdc1394-22-dev

and the output is
Reading package lists...Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information...Done

Package python-numpy is not available, but is referred to by another package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source.

What can I do?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `python3-numpy`

python2 is obsolete and not included in Raspberry Pi OS.

If you are following any examples which use python2 try something up to date.

Answer (score 0):

You may use pip to install numpy instead. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21305524/how-to-install-pip-for-python-2) about how to install pip for py2. Once you got pip , installing numpy will be something like:

`pip install numpy` or `pip2 install numpy` or `python -m pip install numpy`

The last one implies that `python` linked to your py2 installation and `pip` is installed in path.

Additionally if you can use python 3 instead, better do so as python 2 is closed and no longer supported.